# Angular UnitTest inner spec files not consider and also fdescribe, xdescribe, fit and xit not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, tsconfig, testcasesource

When we run Angular Application UnitTest with
**ng test** not running all test cases
even adding  fdescribe, xdescribe, fit and xit not considered

**Example:** deeppath is not considered
1.src\app\modules\sample\sample.spec.ts considered
2.src\app\modules\sample\example\example.spec.ts not considered

I tried changing below file
**tsconfig.spec.json**

1.
`"include": [ "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts" ]`

2.`"include": [ "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.d.ts" ]`
3.`"include": [ "*.spec.ts", "*.d.ts" ]`

Answer (score 0):

In `test.ts`, can you look for this line and ensure that the regular expression is accurate and it should find all of your tests?

```
...
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```